# Text Link to results page with search parameters passed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search

In my database is a column named "**startDate**". An example of a stored startDate is **2000-01-01 12:01:01.000000**. (This date is different than the Created_at or modified_at dates. It would be the date of when the event mentioned in this view's show.html.erb occurred.)

In a show view for an article, I would like to link to a results (index) page where similar microposts would be displayed. I am not sure how to do this.

The text with links may say something like:

> There are 17 events within 10 days before or after the date Wednesday
>   October 17th, 2009.

The words "**17 events**" would be a link to a results page. The span of the search in this particular example would be **20 days** in total with **10 days** before **Wednesday October 17th, 2009**, and **10 days after**.

this is my current show.html.erb page.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span2"><center><img src=<%= @micropost.imageURL %> class="img-polaroid"></center></div>

  <div class="span7">
        <h3><%= @micropost.title %></h3><br>
        <p><small><%= @micropost.loc1T %><br>
            <%= @micropost.startTime.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y') %></small></p>
        <p><%= raw @micropost.content %></p>
    </div>

  <div class="span3"><img src="http://placehold.it/210x210" class="img-polaroid"><br>
    <small>advertisment</small>
    <div class="divider">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="well">

    <p>There are <%= link_to(pluralize("event", @microposts.count), "#{microposts_path} related=#{@micropost.id}") %> within 10 days...</p>


  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

models/micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title,:keyword,:privacy,:groups,:loc1T,:latitude,:longitude,:loc2T,:loc2Lat,:loc2Lon,:startTime,:endTime,:imageURL
  geocoded_by :loc1T
  after_validation :geocode#, :if => :address_changed?


  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :keyword, presence: true
  validates :privacy, presence: true
  validates :groups, presence: true
  validates :loc1T, presence: true
  validates :latitude, presence: true
  validates :longitude, presence: true
  validates :loc2T, presence: true
  validates :loc2Lat, presence: true
  validates :loc2Lon, presence: true
  validates :startTime, presence: true
  validates :endTime, presence: true
  validates :imageURL, presence: true

  validates :content, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'microposts.created_at DESC'

  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                         WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", 
          user_id: user.id)
  end

  def related_microposts(this_startTime)
  @microposts.where('startTime > ? AND startTime < ?', 5.days.since(startTime), 5.days.until(startTime))
  end
end
```

microposts_controller.rb

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def index
  end

   def show
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  end

  def related_microposts(this_startDdate)
  Micropost.where('startDate > ? AND startDate < ?', 5.days.since(this_startDate), 5.days.until(this_startDate))
  end

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

this is a screenshot of the database columns...

[image: DB Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there are a couple of problems to solve.

(following Rails convention, I am going to assume your column is really called `start_date` :-))

First, to get the list of articles whose `start_date` is within 5 days of the article's, you could use something like

```
def related_articles(this_start_date)
  Article.where('start_date > ? AND start_date < ?', 5.days.since(this_start_date), 5.days.until(this_start_date))
end
```

I might have the time functions wrong, but [check here for details](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html).

Now `related_articles` has what you need.  If all you need is the count, you can get it with `related_articles.count`, or perhaps save to `@articles`.  In the main page displaying the current `@article` add a link to display related articles, like

```
There are <%= link_to(pluralize("event", @articles.count), "#{articles_path}?related=#{@article.id}") %> within 10 days...
```

`articles_path` is the path to your `index` view that lists all articles, so now put some code in the controller's `index` method to list just those articles when the special query string parameter is present.

```
if params[:related]
  this_article = Article.find params[:related]  # 123 is the id of the main article
  @articles = Article.related_articles(this_article)
else
  @articles = Article.all
end
```

Kind of a disorganized answer, but I think it gets at the main points :-)

Comment: I think I may have thrown you off by using the word "articles" in my post. Everything in my post relates to a db named "microposts". I tried your code and substituted the word "article" with "micropost". I am assuming your first block of code goes into the **microposts_controller.rb**, and the second goes into  **show.html.erb**  I've updated my original post with what I tried. In the end I get error message: undefined method 'count' for nil:NilClass. Oh, and I did name my column "startDate". I'm a newbie.

Comment: Newbies welcome.  I'm one too, and have been doing Rails since 2007.  But any code I posted is just a general gist of what you need to do.  The very first block `def related_articles...` goes in your `micropost.rb` model.  The second ("There are <%= link_to...") goes in the view (`show.html.erb`).  The last goes in the controller.  My advice is to break the problem into chunks.  Look at the development.log file to see what you get when you go to any page on your site -- in particular, the path and params array.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I hope this gets easier with time. I tried your solution again., but in the show.html.erb, I get the following error: `undefined method 'count' for nil:NilClass` on this line: **<p>There are <%= link_to(pluralize("event", @microposts.count), "#{microposts_path}?related=#{@micropost.id}") %> within 10 days...</p>**. Is there something missing in my microposts_controller.rb?

Comment: livi1717 -- yes, a value for `@microposts` (with the "s") -- because it's missing, ruby defines it as `nil`.  Of course what you meant was to have ruby execute `count` on a collection of microposts.  So: get that collection in the `show` method before the view is displayed. In your updated question, you have the `related_microposts` method defined (I suggest you move it to the model).  In your controller, after you set the value for `@micropost`, you can set a value like `@microposts = related_microposts(@micropost.startDate)`

Comment: Thanks for all your help. This is driving me insane. I tried again, and I am getting a **undefined method `related_microposts' for #<MicropostsController:0x00000103d645a8>** error. **app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:11:in `show'** I've updated my code above